# NSURLConnection (Syncronous Request) returns (null)

Tags: objective-c, nsurlrequest

I want to get HTML from website. I wrote below code but this returns `(null)`.

```
NSString *strURL = @"http://www.googole.com";

- (NSString *)getHtml
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: strURL];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest : req
                                         returningResponse : &response
                                                     error : &error];
    NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return strData;
}
```

Comment: You would know what the problem was if you looked at your error -- that's what it's there for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have mistyped the url.
It should be `NSString *strURL = @"http://www.google.com";`